# React-tsx-Download Multiple image file in Zip format

Tags: reactjs, download, zip, tsx

I want to download zip which contains the multiple images, I use the js-zip but it does not allow me to use jszip-util its show Can not find name JSZipUtils for that because of my TSX file i think. here is some code which I tried..

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import  JSZip from 'jszip';
    import FileSaver from 'file-saver';

    class ZipDemo extends React.Component{
        download =()=>{
        let links:string[]=[
            "https://sequenceimagestaging.blob.core.windows.net/retouch/3xl/100/1610004/one.jpg?v=1569588865599",
             "https://sequenceimagestaging.blob.core.windows.net/retouch/3xl/900/2411015/two.jpg?v=1569588865599",
             "https://sequenceimagestaging.blob.core.windows.net/retouch/l/200/3310029/three.jpg?v=1569588865599",
             "https://sequenceimagestaging.blob.core.windows.net/retouch/m/300/3237036/four.jpg?v=1569588865599",
             "https://sequenceimagestaging.blob.core.windows.net/retouch/s/400/5372009/five.jpg?v=1569588865599"
        ];
        var zip = new JSZip();
        var count = 0;
        var zipFilename = "Pictures.zip";  
        links.forEach(function (url, i) {
          var filename = links[i];
          filename = filename.replace(/[\/\*\|\:\<\>\?\"\\]/gi, '').replace("httpssequenceimagestaging.blob.core.windows.netretouch","");
          JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true });
            count++;
            if (count == links.length) {
              zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
                FileSaver.saveAs(content, zipFilename);
              });
            }
          });
        });
    }

    render() { 
        return (  
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.download}>click me </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ZipDemo;
```

I took reference from  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaitsujin/zrdgsjht/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let blob = fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
    zip1.file(filename, blob, { binary: true });
```

add this 2 line in space of

```
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true });
```

it works very well because jszip-utils module is not available in typescript i think I am not sure, so it is the alternate way to convert the file into binary.

Answer (score 0):

JSZipUtils appears to be a separate project, and would need to also be imported. Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip-utils?

Comment: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jszip-utils'. '/home/tushar/Documents/html/my-app/node_modules/jszip-utils/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/jszip-utils` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jszip-utils';`

Comment: Sounds like you have TypeScript configured to require type definitions for modules. jszip-utils doesn't provide type definitions, and it doesn't seem to be on DefinitelyTyped either, so you'll need to write your own or explicitly any-type the module

Comment: can you suggest something for that ,I don't have an idea about that....